# find key in Javascript dictionary where the KEY is less than a certain value.

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Ok first off, let me make it clear that we are talking about the KEY or Index , the value is not important at this time.
What I have is a dictionary with numeric keys example:

```
var someDict = {1:"First value", 2:"Second value", 5:"Some other value", 12:"Some other value."}
```

Because when they are added it may be out of order.
So if I do

```
 someDict[4] = "This goes before 5";
```

there's no problem.

What I want to do is just before I add the 4 key to this dictionary, I need to know what was the key that I already have before it in the sequence. In this example that would be key 2. 
Is there any way to find this out besides looping through my dictionary manually?  Something similar :

```
var myKey = someDict[lastkey < 4].Key
```

jQuery based is acceptable answer too.

Comment: If your keys are numbers that kinda represent an index - why don't you use an array?

Comment: `((Object.keys(someDict)).filter(function(value){return value < 4;})).pop();`

Comment: @Slonski because it's only quasi index like, calling someDict.length would return 13 in this example(1+ the last element in the array) . When the correct answer is 4 . Besides my real index numbers represent thousands of a second, and these entries are minutes apart, so it's more like myDict={21314241245:"Something",43234450003:"Something Else"} If it was an array all the indexes inbetween would exsist but be = to undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var someDict = {1:"First value", 2:"Second value", 5:"Some other value", 12:"Some other value."}

var keys = Object.keys(someDict);
var lowerKeys = keys.filter(function(value){
  return value < 4;
})
var myKey = lowerKeys.pop();
console.log(myKey);
```